# Need to bind the data in Spinner drop down in android with an class

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am using an spinner drop down in my android application, i am having the class with an list from that i need to bind the data in my drop down.But i am not getting what i have set in the list instead its showing an **"com.example.testuser.applicationmae.class"**.

Below i have attached my code that i have used

```
  desiginations = EmpDtls.getDesiginations();
    spinnerOfferType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerOfferType);

    ArrayAdapter<Desigination> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Desigination>(
           this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,desiginations);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerOfferType.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Employee Class as follow

```
public class EmpDtls {

public String EmpName;
public String EmpJDate;

public static List<Desigination> getDesiginations(){

    List<Desigination> desiginations = new ArrayList<Desigination>();
    Desigination desigination = new Desigination();
    desigination.id = 1;

    desigination.name = "Application Developer";

    desiginations.add(desigination);
    desigination = new Desigination();

    desigination.id = 2;
    desigination.name = "Manager";

    desiginations.add(desigination);

    return  desiginations;
 }

}
```

My Designation Class as follow

```
public class Desigination {
public int id;
public String  name;
}
```

Comment: Add Desigination class to question

Comment: @cricket_007 i have attached my Desigination respectively .

Comment: Add a toString method to it